# django, PointField or DecimalField for latitude, longitude

Tags: django, geolocation

I'm going to use latitude/longitude to show a google map.

Later on, I might use it to do a nearby search.

Would it be a wise decision to start using GeoDjango's PointField?

Comment: If you use google-maps(javascript), then decimalfield should be enough to pass data to template to display map

Answer (score 0):

Setting up GeoDjango was easier than I expected.

nearby search comes with GeoDjango.

Definitely worth a shot.